# sidr - Is it possible to change the menu color dynamically

Tags: sidr

Using sidr menus...  I can see where I can specify a theme ... like sidr.light.css or create my own.  I am wondering, is it possible to dynamically change the text color or background color of the menu using javascript?   I would assume so, but not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, like any other element on your page, this question is not Sidr related.

If you want to change the CSS of an element dinamically with jQuery, you can do this (for example):

```
$('.sidr').css({
    color: '#ff0000',
    background: '#0000ff'
});
```

Where `'.sidr'` should be the selector of the element you want to change.